# Prove that G is a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Suppose that $|G| = pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are  primes such that $p < q$ and $p$ does not divide $q − 1$. Prove that $G$ is a cyclic group.

A cyclic group is a group that has a unique generator element, so is the way to go with this to find that element? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes, is that what to use here?

Comment: It's a convenient way. There are others.

Comment: To be more precise, do you know the fact that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ divides $|G|$ and has the form $kp+1$ for some integer $k$? Compare that with the statement of the question.

Answer (score 2):

A precedent question shows [Prove that G has a normal Sylow p-subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621692/prove-that-g-has-a-normal-sylow-p-subgroup) that $G$ has a Sylow normal group $N$ of order $p$, Consider $m:G\rightarrow G/N$ it defines an extension $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow G/N\rightarrow 1$ this extension splits since the theorem of Sylow implies that $G$ has a $q$-subgroup, but it is trivial since splitting extensions of $Z/p$ by $Z/q$  are classified by morphisms $Z/q\rightarrow Aut(Z/p)$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Classifying_split_extensions but any action of $Z/p$ on $Z/p$ is trivial since $p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers and $p$ does not divide $q-1$. This implies that $G=Z/p\times Z/q$.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If $p-1\mid q $ there are nontrivial actions!

Answer (score 2):

In my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1617153/299525) I showed that any such group must be abelian. Now it is a general fact that an abelian group of order $pq$ where $p \ne q$ are primes, then the group is cyclic. The goal is to produce elements of order $p$ and $q$ and then find the order of the product.

The advantage of this approach is that it can be done **without** Sylow Theorems.